# SQL Service Broker & Logical File Names

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

A colleague was having trouble enabling the Service Broker for a particular database.  SQL Server kept on throwing an error stating that the Service Broker was already running. When checking the database, the option for Service Broker was disabled.

It turns out that the database was created using a backup of another database and the logical names had not been changed. The original database did indeed have the Service Broker enabled.

So in summary we have:

- `DB1` with logical names `foo` and `foo_log` with Service Broker enabled
- `DB2` with logical names `foo` and `foo_log` with Service Broker disabled

We were unable to start Service Broker on `DB2` as SQL Server said it was already running. The databases were pointing to different `.mdf` & `.ldf` files.

Why does the Service Broker use the logical names and not the database names? I always thought that the scope of logical name was restricted to a single database?

**EDIT**

This is the SQL Statement that was used to enable Service Broker

`ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`

And the error is:

```
Msg 9772, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The Service Broker in database "DB2" cannot be enabled because there is already an enabled Service Broker with the same ID.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Comment: @@Barry share the TSQL statements that you are using to enable service broker?

Comment: If you look at the error, it clearly indicates you that you are trying to enable Service Broker against a 'Service_Broker_Guid' which is already been used by some other database, there you need to run Step 2 of my answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the logical file names...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I realise that now. It led me down the garden path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 4 steps to enable service broker for a Database and non of them use logical file name as parameter

Try this

```
USE MASTER
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  is_broker_enabled, Service_Broker_Guid,*
            FROM    sys.databases
            WHERE   name = 'DB2'
                    AND is_broker_enabled = 0 ) 
BEGIN                    

    -- Step 1 ---  Rollback running transactions and brings the database in a single user mode.
    ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE


    -- Step 2 --- To avoid distributed conversation and OLD database GUID conflicts.
    ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET NEW_BROKER;


    -- Step 3 --- Set the is_broker_enabled flag to true  
    ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET ENABLE_BROKER;


    -- Step 4 --- Brings the database back to Multi user mode and allow shared locks\connections.
    ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

END
```

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of `NEW_BROKER`. That makes sense to me now.

Comment: No need to switch to single user. You can run directly `ALTER DATABASE DB2 SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`.